# SharePoint 2010 Taxonomy and URLs

Tags: taxonomy, url

Can anyone explain if there is a relationship in SharePoint 2010 between the meta data services/taxonomy and the url of list items?

Answer (score 1):

If you tag pages (not items) in SharePoint, this is done by URL. If the URL changes (e.g. by renaming), the tags are getting lost ;-( This is a showstopper in case of organizing an portal using tags.